# How to debug on whether observable is unsubscribe

Tags: rxjs, observable

how can i test whether the observable is unsubscribe after subscription.
I am developing in ionic2/angular2.

I am expecting typing something like this in chrome developer mode and it will return value:
`observableName.isSubscribe()`

Answer (score 15):

You can have a subscription and check closed parameter.

```
let subscription = observable.subscribe(() => {})

if (!subscription.closed) {
  //subscribed
} else {
  //not subscribed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As sebaferreras told in the last comment, you can just use the `closed` property;

So, for example:

```
const sub$ = new Subject();
sub$.unsubscribe();
sub$.closed //true;
```