# How to get to know whether an observable is unsubscribed?

Tags: angular

I have an observable and i am unsubscribing it. After unsubscription i want to check whether it is actually unsubscribed or not. 
In my below code i have created an Observable and i am completing my observer so that it won't receive any emit value. Now i am checking the status of my subscription which is true but I have not unsubscribed the observable yet.

```js
let _data = Observable.create((observer:Observer<any>)=>    
{
  observer.next('1');observer.next('3');observer.complete());
  let subscription:Subscription = _data.subscribe(res=> res});
 console.log(subscription.closed);
```

As explained above subscription.closed return true in case of unicast observable. But if i am using multicast observable like Subject that it will return false so in that case it is not unsubscribed but it will not emit values.

```js
let sub = new Subject<any>();
    sub.complete();
    console.log(sub.closed);
// return false in this case.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug on whether observable is unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46221549/how-to-debug-on-whether-observable-is-unsubscribe)

Comment: No it does not.